# Gmap - get coordinates of point you are centered in

Tags: c#, geolocation

I'm new to C# and i'm looking to develop a simple application with desktop and mobilie functionality.

To put it in a few words, it's an app to help the police(it's a fun project by the way). So someone in the station get's a call and a person that needs a police at a place, tells him the address. You put the address in the desktop app, map goes to that point and you store all the data of that call.
Then a police on duty, on his mobile, gets all that info, including the coordinates, and with the GPS gets the fastest route to that adress and drives.

So i am using Gmap, i can input the adress just fine and center a map on it on the desktop application. Problem is that i can't find any function that gets the coordinates of that point where i'm aiming at...

Does anyone know how can i do this?

Thank you

Comment: Well i like the idea of your app... but making it a desktop app is not the best idea since google maps is only supported for android ios and web. but if you do want to do it that way look at this. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889136/Csharp-Google-Maps-in-WinForm-with-WebBrowser-and

Comment: @AlfredAlfizoMosima Hi there. Well no problem with Gmap using google maps at least. It allows to use Bing, Yahoo, Google maps with no problem for what i've tested until now. My problem is to get the coordinates of the point i am looking at...

Comment: Yeah but you need to post code here so we can see what you have done so far. otherwise we cant help you....

Comment: The other issue is it will never get the coordinates correct of your location since there is no gps sensor. it will only use your internet connection to try locate your position.

Comment: If you want to have something useful... build a mobile app that the person can log their position of where the incident is. Then the desktop app will be used by the police just to read coordinates of the incident.

Comment: @AlfredAlfizoMosima i get what you are saying but i really want to make it this way. It's just a fun project. I can post some code here, but what i have is basicly this:
http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/

Answer (score 0):

Okey i found out a way to do it. I was messing with MapPoint X and Y, but it's Position that matters.

```
latitude = gmap.Position.Lat;
longitude = gmap.Position.Lng;
```

Where latitude and longitude are doubles, and gmap is the map itself.